# Uninstallation trouble (Wubi windows 7)

Tags: boot, wubi

I recently installed Ubuntu as a second boot option on my windows 7 system. I had a difficulty on boot Ubuntu so I tried to uninstall it through control panel. I couldn't find any ubuntu program on control panel so I formatted the partition in which ubuntu was installed. Now my problem is that ubuntu is shown on my boot screen (although it is deleted). Is there any way to fix this issue?

BTW ubuntu boot option is shown twice because of an other attempt to uninstalling it.
This issue is bugging me for a week now!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via command line of windows 7. The application is called `bcdedit`.

Easiest way would be :

Download [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD) and modify the windows bootloader. It is free for non commercial usage.

Just delete the ubuntu related entries.

Comment: i just delete those two ubuntu entries and that's it??? nothing else to do to delete any remaining files or anything like that?

Comment: ubuntu installed through wubi create `root.disk` file. Since you said you have formated that partition, I assumed you have deleted those file. Have a look here http://askubuntu.com/q/128901/35775